# Building from Source on CentOS 5 or newer

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, software-installation, make

I've got a few applications of which I've got to build from source files in order to make it work on CentOS (the programs do not exist in the yum repos).

I may be missing something, but unlike Debian and others, where the `make` command is readily available, this program does not exist in CentOS out of the box.

What is needed to allow for me to build an application from source on CentOS 5 or newer?  Or does this option even exist in the first place?  (NOTE: This is a command-line accessible system only, so all solutions must utilize only the command line interface)

Answer (score 1):

Try `yum install make`. Also consider getting things like gcc, autoconf, automake, etc. I don't know what CentOS  comes with out of the box, but I'm sure those things are available in the repositories. You might need devel packages for any libraries that the program you are compiling references as well.

Comment: Perhaps there is some meta-package to get the most basic build related stuff?

Comment: @maxschlepzig: There might be actually, but I don't know what it is on CentOS/RHEL. You?

Comment: @maxschlepzig: Not sure if this is portable, but from the docs @Steven linked it looks like that would be `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"` on Fedora. Can somebody with CentOS confirm this?

Comment: no I don't know. @Caleb Reading your 2nd comment I vaguely remember selecting something like during a Fedora install.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read through some of [this documentation](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package). The first bit goes through installing development tools.

Comment: except there are no RPM files for this.  Otherwise, the question would have been "How do I create an RPM?" and not "How do I build something from source?"

Comment: I should have said "**Even if you don't**, the first bit of that document goes through installing development tools."

Comment: @Steven: Answers here are editable so you can fix things like that when you see them for the benefit of future readers. I edited your answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall, the default CentOS install is server install. You can custom install a development environment.

The *right* way to get these applications on would be to build RPM's (preferably in mock). You may be able to start with the current Fedora src.rpm though some editing of the RPM spec file quite likely will be required.

Before you do all that, though, check to see if what you need is already packaged in EPEL.